# For the DVR8825 IC chip (not the carrier/module), nSleep and nReset need to be HIGH, why does connecting them to the IC's 3.3V out not work?

Tags: logic-level, stepper-driver

A breadboard prototype was made using the [DVR8825 carrier/module](https://www.pololu.com/product/2133):

[image]

A microcontroller's HIGH was connected to nReset and nSleep. Now a prototype was made using the IC/chip. It's 3.3V output was connected to nReset and nSleep:

[image]

The circuit looks like this, with the 0.47uF cap and everything, except for that change:

[image]

([Page 18](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf#page=18) of the datasheet.)

It works when 3.3V from an external supply is connected, but otherwise the IC/chip's V3P3OUT is zero volts. [This TI page](https://e2e.ti.com/support/motor-drivers-group/motor-drivers/f/motor-drivers-forum/848500/drv8825-about-v3p3out-15pin) mentions something about their application's load current being more than 1mA, so they did not use the V3P3OUT:

[image]

The layout example shows them separated:

[image]

([Page 22](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf#page=22) of the datasheet.)

Both nReset and nSleep need to be HIGH. So is there a current mismatch? What other reason explains why 3.3V from the IC cannot be connected as logic HIGH to other pins on the IC?

[image]

Comment: Breadboard really?

Comment: I didn't read the datasheet but my guess is that the internal ldo that generates V3P3OUT is off when the chip is in reset/standby.

Comment: Driving nSLEEP low will put the device into a low power sleep state. In this state, the H-bridges are disabled, the
gate drive charge pump is stopped, the V3P3OUT regulator is disabled, and all internal clocks are stopped.  This is from page 17.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. When 3v3 is touched momentarily, it starts up and keeps going.